# Is there such thing as a variable for my whole solution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Seems very beginner,
but I have a big solution, and the problem is when a user is in a subroutine I store the date in a variable in frmMain.vb, which is based in project 1. After the user steps into a user control in Project B, I need to have the same value which previously the user stored in the frmMain.vb.

Could You please guide me through on how it is possible?

Comment: To confirm, you have two separate projects, and you want a variable which is visible in both projects.

Comment: frmFacility.vb and its user control is ucBookCtrl.vb

Answer (score 3):

Forget all this noise about how you can use a global variable. The fact that you're asking this question implies that you're new to the language and want to learn the right way of doing things. **That's great!**

But the real answer is a little bit more complicated. The truth is, global variables have mostly fallen out of favor for modern programming tasks. VB.NET in particular (as with *many* other popular languages) is an *object-oriented* language, which means that you interact with methods on individual instances of objects. Object-oriented programming provides a host of benefits, but also presents a whole new set of challenges. If you don't already have a good book that you're learning VB.NET from, I *highly* suggest that you stop now and pick one up.

It's far easier to pick up good habits in the beginning than it is to *unlearn* bad habits later. And trust me, global variables are a bad habit and the wrong way to write code in VB.NET. There *are* ways to do it, but you don't want to use those. Ignore them at all costs. The temptation to do it the "easy" way isn't worth it.

The quick, executive summary is that you need to create a *public property* in your form's class. (Remember, in VB.NET, a form is just an instance of a class. It simply inherits from the `Form` class so that it gets all of the base functionality for free.) A public property is *sort* of like a global variable in that it allows other classes to access that value from outside, but it's the preferred way of doing things in object-oriented languages. In VB.NET, the code for a public property might look something like this:

```
Public Class MyForm : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    ' Private field (variable), only visible from inside of this class
    Private myFavoriteColor As Color = Color.Blue

    ' Public property to expose favorite color to other classes
    Public Property FavoriteColor As Color
        Get
            ' Returns the value of the private variable
            Return myFavoriteColor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            ' Sets the private variable to the specified value
            myFavoriteColor = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' ... the rest of your form code would go here
End Class
```

And then from *outside* of your form, you might have the following code:

```
Public Class SecondForm : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Sub MyMethod
        ' Create an instance of the MyForm class
        Dim frm As MyForm = New MyForm()

        ' Show that form
        frm.Show()

        ' Read the value of its favorite color property,
        ' and display it in a message box
        MessageBox.Show(frm.FavoriteColor.ToString)

        ' ... do whatever else you want to do with that form

        ' Close the form
        frm.Close()
    End Sub

    ' ... other code for the second form might go here
End Class
```

Notice how we were able to read the value of a variable stored inside of the `frm` object (an instance of the `MyForm` class) from inside of a completely *different* class? This way, you avoid storing *global* state information. Instead, you've kept those variables (and the information they contain) enclosed within the particular classes that they apply to. And you didn't have to reach in and touch that other class object's private parts, because it exposed them to you properly using a public property. That's the right way to do this. As I mentioned above, make sure that you're learning from a good book that teaches you object-oriented programming along with the other basics. You'll regret doing it any other way.

Comment: I understand But It needs to have a refrence to another project in my situation which I am avoiding it, that's why! Since they are not actually in the same level in the application.

Comment: @amir: How/why do you have two objects open simultaneously that know nothing about the other? Your question says that it's a user control—what form is hosting that user control, and how do you show it? Presumably your "main" form is responsible for creating an instance of that user control and showing it on the screen. You could then implement this on your main form as shown. It's difficult to be any more specific without a better description of your design (feel free to edit your question with more details), but global variables are almost *always* the wrong way.

Comment: Ok, let me put it this way: i am developing a system for newer version. This Main form has an instance and I know I can Create a constructor, but this project is as huge as an elephant and Everything is desinged at runtime in usercontrol constructor, That is why I avoid adding a new constructor and pass in the date variable as a parameter.

Comment: @amir: That doesn't stop you from creating a new constructor that *calls* the other one. Just add a new constructor that accepts an additional parameter, and then make the first line a call to the existing constructor. If you don't pass the new parameter, it will find the correct overload, and everything will work as expected. But I don't really understand why the user control can't just read data from its parent form. Something like `Me.FindForm`, then cast the result to your form's class, and you'll be able to access its properties.

Answer (score 2):

Amir, this is surely possible in different ways but it's really not incouraged.

You are still thinking in the VB6 mode with global variables or objects around.

Comment: Global variables weren't right in VB 6 either. Had this question been asked about VB 6, someone could have rightfully told the OP "you're still thinking in the QuickBASIC mode with global variables".

Answer (score 1):

Is the user control on `frmMain`? You could pass the value into the user control's constructor, if you have control over it.

**Edit:** If you cannot change the constructor, you could add a property on the user control that holds this date, and you could set it when instantiating the control. On the user control, you can check if this value is set before using it (by making it of Nullable DateTime type). For example, on the user control, you could add this:

```
    Private _myDateVariable As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property MyDateVariable() As Nullable(Of Date)
        Get
            Return _myDateVariable
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Date))
            _myDateVariable = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

And then you can access this from frmMain like so (where myUserControl is the instance of your control):

```
myUserControl.MyDateVariable = theDateValueYouWantToSet
```

And when using it on the control:

```
If MyDateVariable.HasValue Then
    'The date has a value, so you can use it
    ' Do something with MyDateVariable.Value
Else
    ' The date has no value, so do something else
End If
```

Comment: I thought of that but unfortunately I am developing to a newer version so less changes is required from my manager!

Answer (score 0):

You can store that variable as a shared variable you can then reference it anywhere in your code.

so in your frmMain.vb you have:

```
Public Shared myVariable as DateTime
```

you can then refer to it anywhere like this:

```
NamespaceProject1.frmMain.myVariable
```

More info here under **Global Values**:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1047/new-objectoriented-capabilities-in-vbnet/5/

**Nevertheless** I would stick with Davide Piras advice  and only do this when needed, too many variables in the global scope will lead to unmaintainable and hard to read spagetty code

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something like a Util project in your solution that is referenced in all other projects?

You could have a global static variable there accessible from everywhere else in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a database as well.